# Modify 'order view' total credit card in one page checkout based on selected currency

Tags: magento

In Magento 1.8.1, if I am changing the base currency then at the final step of the checkout i.e., order review section, we come across a row "Your credit card will be charged for".

I wanted to change the amount shown beside this in the selected currency instead of the base currency of the store! This is the core functionality of Magento but I want to change it.

I think it requires me to override the core code but I don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Hope this works.